# are Model POJOs required in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dao

I am currently playing around with a Spring MVC application, with two tables.

**Student** 
(id, name) and **Publications** (student_id, journal).

In my GET request, I am trying to request all of the Journals (String) of a given student ID. I believe in this case, I can simply do the following in my DAO without using any models:

```
@Override
public List<String> getAllJournals(String name) {
    String query = "SELECT journal FROM Publications INNER JOIN Student ON "
            + "Publications.student_id = Student.id WHERE Student.name=:name";

    Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    params.put("name", name);
    List<String> journals = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, params, String.class);
    return journals;
}
```

Should I be using the POJO for the Publication class or the Student class? Wouldn't this be redundant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good idea to have POJOs, since they allow you to use their attributes instead of making an attribution for each attribute you want to use, just like you did here:

```
List<String> journals = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, params, String.class);
```

Even if it seems a kind of "redundant" thing, using POJOs helps you to have reuse aspect on you code. You can simply create methids that returns all the `Publication` attributes. In your case, this is a very simple entity with just 2 fields, but if this entity grows up, use POJOs could help you with the reuse aspect.

Here is a great aswer about [advantages of using POJOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172621/whats-the-advantage-of-pojo).

Comment: In this if I don't care about the student_ids at all, would it be better to just call the setter on Publications, like `publication.set(journals); return publications;`

Comment: Yes, agreed. If you don't care about reusing object attributes, you can just make a query per result needed.