# Json array not getting from retrofit response

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

In my android app. I am using retrofit2. I want to get json details from the api. The response is coming but the json objects are showing as null. 
I am getting the json objects size. But i did not getting the values. How to parse the json from `response.body`.
I want to get the value of `DATA_TITLE`,`DATA_IMAGE`, `DATA`.

I am first time using retrofit. I have tried different methods. Please help me.

My json code is shown below. And the all source codes are also shown in below.

```
[{
        "ID": {
            "Tag": "string",
            "Method": 5,
            "Value": "68613",
            "status": true
        },
        "DATA_TITLE": {
            "Tag": "string",
            "Method": 5,
            "Value": "Hai aaaaaaa",
            "status": true
        },
        "DATA_IMAGE": {
            "Tag": "string",
            "Method": 5,
            "Value": "http://xxxxxx.com/desktopModules/Farabi.ICatalog/CatalogImages/488/C-2048_sd-eng.jpg",
            "status": true
        },
        "DATA": {
            "Tag": "string",
            "Method": 5,
            "Value": "",
            "status": true
        }
    }, {
        "ID": {
            "Tag": "string",
            "Method": 5,
            "Value": "68613",
            "status": true
        },
        "DATA_TITLE": {
            "Tag": "string",
            "Method": 5,
            "Value": "Hai aaaaaaa",
            "status": true
        },
        "DATA_IMAGE": {
            "Tag": "string",
            "Method": 5,
            "Value": "http://xxxxxx.com/desktopModules/Farabi.ICatalog/CatalogImages/488/C-2048_sd-eng.jpg",
            "status": true
        },
        "DATA": {
            "Tag": "string",
            "Method": 5,
            "Value": "",
            "status": true
        }
    }

]
```

And my gradle code is

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArrayList<List<Objects>> data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ApiInterface apiService =
            ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);


    Call<List<DataResponse>> call =apiService.getDetails(Util.TemplateName,Util.p,Util.Handler,Util.AppName,Util.Type,Util.F);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<DataResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<DataResponse>> call, Response<List<DataResponse>> response) {


            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String json = gson.toJson(response.body());
                List<DataResponse> dataResponses = response.body();
                Log.d("LOG","Response size:"+dataResponses.size());
                Log.d("LOG","Response data:"+dataResponses.get(0).getDataList());

  // I want to get the value of DATA_TITLE,DATA_IMAGE, DATA

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<DataResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("LOG","Response error:"+t);
        }
    });


}
}
```

**ApiInterface**

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@GET("getdetails")
Call<List<DataResponse>> getDetails(@Query("TemplateName") String TemplateName);
}
```

**ApiClient.java**

```
public class ApiClient {
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Util.URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

**DataResponse**

```
public class DataResponse {

private List<Objects> results;
@SerializedName("")
@Expose
private List<Objects> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

public List<Objects> getDataList() {
    return dataList;
}
public List<Objects> getResults() {
    return results;
}
public void setResults(List<Objects> results) {
    this.results = results;
}
}
```

**Objects.java**

```
public class Objects {

@SerializedName("ID")
private String id;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

Comment: when i change to `Call<DataResponse>` it shows the error is Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column2. So i changed to `Call<List<DataResponse>>`

Comment: sorry my bad it should be List<DatResponse> only.

Comment: use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and create our Pojo properly. I think there is some issue in your Pojo only.

Comment: @hasan_shaikh I have created my pojo. Then also the array getting as null.

Answer (score 2):

First of all see if everything is working fine. Replace all your `List<DataResponse>` with `JsonElement` and then hit your webservice.
After getting response in `response.body()`, either parse manually or best way is to copy your response and go to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and create POJO class. After then pass the new POJO class object in your `<PojoObject>` retrofit api. For more on POJO refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14172743/5996106)

Comment: I have created pojo but the result is not getting correctly. The array is showing as null.

Comment: I didn't JsonElement because i didn't understand about how to use JsonElement.

Comment: Jsut replace `List<DataResponse>` with `JsonElement` here 
 `Call<JsonElement> getDetails(@Query("TemplateName") String TemplateName);
}`
in your `ApiInterface` Class.

Answer (score 1):

It's a detail but I am always adding the tag `@Headers` while getting or sending JSON objects.

e.g.

```
  @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @GET("articles")
    Call<String> getArticles();
```