# What is the best way to catch the response from server via Retrofit?

Tags: android, android-studio, gson, retrofit, data-conversion

What is the best way to cast my response from the server ?

1. By directly assigning the response to the entity

```
Ex: authorityStatusWithWorkFlowEntity = response.body();
```

**OR**

2. First Catching it as `JsonElement` **OR** `JsonArray` **OR** `JsonObject` and then  converting it to specified `entity`?

```
Ex: lineEstimationEntity = new Gson().fromJson(response.body().getAsJsonObject(), new TypeToken<LineEstimationEntity>() {
                        }.getType());
```

In performance wise which is the best practice?

Comment: use a gson convertor and you can directly deal with data class/pojos.

Comment: There are two ways of doing it. Firstly, you can do some pure work like using the response and serializing/deserializing it and getting the data out of it. Secondly, you can have good use of GSON with retrofit while you configure your retrofit `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` and down the line, you can go for either RxJava or Kotlin's flow API

Comment: @Raghunandan Which is the best practice in terms of performance?

Comment: @AkshayNandwana Which is the best practice in terms of performance?

Comment: @SandeepKulkarni I think POJO is the best for catch the response from server. Here is the further advantages. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14172743/7498057

Comment: @SandeepKulkarni you get the json converted to pojo while using a gson convertor instead of manually parsing the json yourself. it is what most people do so there is not a lot to worry about performance